# How to pass data from main activity to BroadcastReciever in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I am trying to pass some value from `class GeofenceBroadcastReceiver : BroadcastReceiver()` to MainActivity but it doesn't seem to be working

```
class GeofenceBroadcastReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {

override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {

      val intent = Intent(this, HuntMainActivity::class.java)
      intent.putExtra("nameValue", "My name")
```

its giving an error on Intent, I also tried to write name of Activity after `this@`,
I am very new to coding and kotlin so my apologies in Advance

Comment: what is the error you are receiving?

Comment: override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {


        val intent = Intent(this@GeofenceBroadcastReceiver, HuntMainActivity::class.java)
        intent.putExtra("nameValue", "My name")

Error says none of the following functions can be called with the arguments provided

Comment: try instead of this context: val intent = Intent(context,HuntMainActivity::class.java)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Intent's first argument is Context type, but your passing your BroadcastReceiver class that have no context.
instead, you need to use the context object that you received with "onReceive" call.
so, replace:

```
val intent = Intent(this, HuntMainActivity::class.java)
```

with:

```
val intent = Intent(context, HuntMainActivity::class.java)
```